# GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays debian 9 ssh -X

Tags: firefox, ssh, debian

I have two remote systems, both running Debian 9 and are up-to-date.

Both were installed about the same time and have nearly the same configuration.

I can ssh -X to one and run Firefox with out problems
The other one gives me the "GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays" error.

What should I look for?

Bob

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Comment: Answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250580/error-gdk-backend-does-not-match-available-displays-running-selenium-using-cro